# Make a one line data to a table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a record like

```
SWD Lead QA Lead PD Lead Business Manager
AAAA     BBBB    CCCC    DDDD
```

I want to use T-SQL to get a result like below with the column name

```
SWD Lead         AAAA
QA Lead          BBBB
PD Lead          CCCC
Business Manager DDDD
```

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Best Regards,

Comment: Will it always be only one row?

Comment: What are the column names for the result columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2005 you can use [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx). This is modified from the example on that page:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB
FROM Table1
UNPIVOT (ColB FOR ColA IN ([SWD Lead],
                           [QA Lead],
                           [PD Lead],
                           [Business Manager])) AS unpvt;
```

Result:

```
ColA              ColB
SWD Lead          AAAA
QA Lead           BBBB
PD Lead           CCCC
Business Manager  DDDD
```

On older server versions you could do something like this to achieve the same effect:

```
SELECT 'Col1', Col1 FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Col2', Col2 FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Col3', Col3 FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Col4', Col4 FROM Table1
```

Comment: SELECT ColA,ColB
FROM *
   (SELECT *
   FROM dbo.table ) p 
UNPIVOT
   (ColA FOR ColB IN 
      ('QA Lead', 'SW Lead')
) As unpvt

I got a error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '*'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'p'.
"

Comment: +1, useful answer. Slight correction - when I pasted this into management studio, it required  'as my_pivot_table_name;' at the end

Comment: @Yonwei Xing: You have an incorrect * after your first FROM. Instead of posting your question with fake column names, just include your real column names in the question and I can create the query to exactly work in your situation so that you don't have to modify it at all. This will reduce the risk of you making a mistake while changing the column names, as the query will work as-is.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Thnaks very much. There are four colum names QA Lead, SWD Lead, PD Lead, Business Manager.

Comment: Your column names are slightly tricky because they include spaces. To get around this you can surround the names by square brackets. See my updated answer.